# setting this.Background does nothing silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, background-color

Not sure if Im doing something stupid here but this is my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      string s = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["type"];
      if ( s == "add")
      {
          this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
      }
      else
      {
          this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
      }
}
```

Nothing happens? The page doesn't change colour? The query string comes in perfectly fine. I click a button on the main page and there I say `frameMain.Navigate(new Uri("/AddEdit.xaml?type=edit", UriKind.Relative));`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to goto the Xaml for your page and add `Background="Blue"` to the top-level `navigation:Page` element that wouldn't have any effect either.

The top level child of the `Page` most likely is a panel type such as a `Grid` and most likely given the default name `LayoutRoot`.  Hence change your code to this:-

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
      string s = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["type"]; 
      if ( s == "add") 
      { 
          LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
          LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); 
      } 
}
```

**Explanation**

Only the `Border` element and `Panel` elements actually have a working implementation of `Background`.

The `Control` base type also has a `Background` property but it has no idea what to do with it.  It leaves it up to the control template to decide what to do with the `Background` property.  In most cases the template will contain a top level `Border` that will have amoungst other things `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` which passes on the control's `Background` value to the border for display.

Both `Page` and `UserControl` derive from `Control` hence they both acquire the `Background` property.  However not having a template neither of these controls will have any use for the property and modifying it has no effect on anything.

Comment: lol! wow that was simple. I feel so stupid! I guess frustration at 1am can really make you blind! Thanks Anthony Bonus points to you! =)